# Set membership test in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

Simple question: How to filter rows based on set membership? For example, I want to know if r.row('color') is in the set ['red', 'green', 'blue'].

I can write this as a set of "or" expressions, but this seems inefficient, especially if the set is large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it. (Note: this is how you would structure the query in javascript. It may be slightly different depending on your programming language).

```
r.db('YOUR_DB').table('YOUR_TABLE').filter(
  function(doc) {
    return r.expr(['red', 'green', 'blue']).contains(doc('color'))
  }
)
```

This is a handy guide that shows you how to build common SQL queries in ReQL:

https://rethinkdb.com/docs/sql-to-reql/javascript/

In this case we're talking about an `IN` clause in SQL.